# Connecting kendo multiselect with @childview in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a custom kendo filter applied to grid (filtered column from this grid below).

```
<kendo-grid-column field="applianceUserFullName" title="Zgłaszający">
            <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
                         let-column="column"
                         let-filter="filter"
                         let-filterService="filterService">
                <kendo-multiselect #authorList style="width:220px"
                                   [data]="this.distAuthors"
                                   textField="applianceUserFullName"
                                   valueField="applianceUserFullName"
                                   [valuePrimitive]="true"
                                   [filterable]="true"
                                   [value]="authorFilters(filter)"
                                   (valueChange)="authorChange($event, filterService)"
                                   [placeholder]="'Wybierz wartość'">
                </kendo-multiselect>

            </ng-template>
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                {{dataItem.applianceUserFullName}}
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

I would like to be able to filter data from multiselect when typing to textbox above like in this example:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/filtering/

The problem is: element bound here: `@ViewChild("authorList") public authorList: MultiSelectComponent;` is still undefined (which causes further errors).
Extract from my typescript code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        const contains = value => s => s.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        console.log("After view init");
        //if (this.authorList !== undefined) {
            this.authorList.filterChange.asObservable().switchMap(value => Observable.from([this.distAuthors])
                .do(() => this.authorList.loading = true)
                .delay(1000)
                .map((data) => data.filter(contains(value))))
                .subscribe(x => {
                    this.distAuthors = x;
                    this.authorList.loading = false;
                });
        //}
    }
```

Is there anything I can do wrong about that?
Or maybe this cannot be done this way, if so: what is the proper way of doing such filter?

Comment: you should be able to access the viewchild afterViewInit() can u try  this `@ViewChild("authorList") public authorList: any;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filterable MultiSelect in the template and handle the *filterChange* event:

```
<kendo-multiselect
                         [filterable]="true"
                        (filterChange)="onMSFilterChange($event)"...

public onMSFilterChange(e) {
      if(e.length) {
        this.filteredCategories = this.initialCategories
        .filter(cat => cat.CategoryName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(e.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1); 
      } else {
        this.filteredCategories = this.initialCategories;
      }
    }
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/uGVpodb9ItS07qQFDn2b?p=preview)